# Did Genghis Khan outlaw hunting during breeding seasons?

Tags: history, genghis-khan

[9gag.com](http://9gag.com/gag/a9POyy6/good-guy-genghis-khan) claims,

> Genghis Khan forbade the selling of women,
>   theft of other's properties, decreed religious
>   freedom, outlawed hunting during breeding
>   seasons, and exempted the poor from
>   taxation.

[image: Genghis Khan]

Is the claim that he "outlawed hunting during breeding
seasons" true?

Comment: 9gag is missing other notable claims (e.g. enforced religious tolerance, etc....).

Comment: Voting to close this one, as It's a re-posing of his previous question here with minor word changes: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/did-genghis-khan-forbid-the-selling-of-women-and-exempt-the-poor-from-taxation

Comment: @tuskiomi It's not a duplicate. I deliberately split the 3 claims into two questions.

Comment: That is not needed. You have one claim,  you have one question.

Comment: @tuskiomi What is that specific *one claim*?

Comment: A claim is a single claim,  if it comes from a single article (especially if it's one of the sideshow websites)  claims may be similar to one another,  or even say the same thing (you can have multiple claims saying the same thing in a question as well. But only one main claim ), but if an article has multiple claims,  79% of the time,  it belongs in the same question (100% if it's in the same sentence).

Comment: I think it should be 3 questions, not just 2

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ecology for Millions](https://books.google.com/books?id=AcqLH6zh9b0C&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=genghis%20khan%20hunting%20breeding%20season&source=bl&ots=9iio9P_UI8&sig=waVk3NYHoBdKqS3Z7nfrzeMiacI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijk-ugo7vQAhUCrlQKHXKGAVIQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=genghis%20khan%20hunting%20breeding%20season&f=false), it was [Kublai Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kublai_Khan), grandson of Genghis, who outlawed hunting of hare, does, stags and roebuck by kings and nobleman between May and October, which was breeding season.

See also: [Virginia Wildlife, Volumes 28-29](https://books.google.com/books?id=-aNLAQAAMAAJ&q=khan%20hunting%20%22breeding%20season%22&dq=khan%20hunting%20%22breeding%20season%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih3YPUn7zQAhVB5SYKHZqwCmQQ6AEILjAE) (1967)

> In the Mongol Empire of Asia in 1259 the Great Kahn, Kublai Kahn, prohibited hunting through the game breeding seasons (March - September)

Comment: "Nobelmen"? Does that mean they could send out their servants? Or pay a commoner to do it?

Comment: @fredsbend I think it means no sport hunting, but hunting for necessity is ok

Comment: @DavePhD This was closed as a duplicate, so you may want to merge this with you answer on the other question.